# Firebase Storage security rules playground "Simulated read denied"

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want my user to be able to read and write only his own data but. When I test the rules, I get the message "Simulator read denied". Please tell where i am wrong? Thanks for your time.

Here the some information :

**RULES**

```
service firebase.storage {
  // Only a user can upload their file, but anyone can view it
  match /users/{userId}/{fileName} {
    allow read ;
    allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
}
```

**LOCATION**

> /b/online-notepad-d43d2.appspot.com/o/WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2/file1.txt

**PROVIDER**

> "password"

**FIREBASE UID**

> WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2

**EMAIL**

> hgaur701@gmail.com

**EMAIL VERIFIED**

> true

**Authentication payload**

```
{
  "uid": "WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2",
  "token": {
    "sub": "WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2",
    "aud": "online-notepad-d43d2",
    "email": "hgaur701@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

**SCREENSHOT**

exact location i am using : "/WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2/file1.txt"
and one more thing i upload this folder and file from upload button.
not from POST request.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: After changing rules still getting same result]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**STILL GETTING SAME RESULT :(**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your samples to show the entire path you're reading? Using a short UID is typically best for this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  please check this edit. exact location i am using : "/WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2/file1.txt" and one more thing i upload this folder and file from upload button. not from POST request. and this is the user UID WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2.

Comment: Your not accessing `/users/$uid`, but `/$uid` for which no access permission is declared. See for a longer explanation the edit to my answer below.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   sorry sir but i am getting same result  please check new edits. and can you please provide an example.  i know your answer is correct but for some reason this solution is not working for me.

Comment: While you may still not have permission in your new test, the mistake in your  original screenshots was that you were accessing a path that you didn't declare any access permissions to. --- I'm not sure what's going wrong in the new situation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Hello frank sir i like to inform you , I found the problem . And problem is missing bucket path  "match /b/{bucket}/o"    thank you so much sir for your help and time.   after including bucket path now my rules playground is running fine.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Now i have only one last question remain . Do i need auth payload for downloading file through download url?

Comment: Download URLs provide public access to anyone who has that URL. No auth is needed with them, which also means you should not use download URLs if you want to secure read access through security rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you define two completely separate clauses:

```
allow read ;
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

So you have an empty read clause, and a non-empty write clause.

You probably want to use:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

---

**Edit for second problem**: as you said in your edit, you are accessing the path `/WkqtgpdUYRUGOBaAfmCByXtVPoT2/file1.txt`, but your rules only define access permissions for `match /users/{userId}/{fileName}`. Since you are only allowing access in `/users/...` and the path you try to use is not in `/users`, the access is denied by the rules.